# Vertical Scrollview with List view in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to display 10 to 20 column from SQLite database into in my `ListView` with vertical and horizontal `ScrollView` in my app. But I don't have any ideas how to create. I have searched the web but I can't find anything. How can I retrieve all 20 column data in `ListView` from SQLite database?

Answer (score 1):

use `cursoradapter` for your listview and use this select statement for retriving only 10 or 20 `item SELECT * FROM`your_table`LIMIT 0, 10 or 20`
please see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_listviews for learning using from cursoradapter

Comment: haha !! We both linked to Vogella. :D

Comment: haha yes I like tutorials of Vogella a lot :D